# How to write decorator without syntactic sugar in python?

Tags: python, properties, decorator, syntactic-sugar

This question is rather specific, and I believe there are many similar questions but not exactly like this.

I am trying to understand syntactic sugar. My understanding of it is that by definition the code always can be written in a more verbose form, but the sugar exists to make it easier for humans to handle. So there is always a way to write syntactic sugar "without sugar" so to speak?

With that in mind, how precisely do you write a decorator without syntactic sugar? I understand it's basically like:

```
# With syntactic sugar
@decorator
def foo():
    pass
    
# Without syntactic sugar
def foo():
    pass
foo = decorator(foo)
```

Except from [PEP 318](https://peps.python.org/pep-0318/)

> Current Syntax
>
> The current syntax for function decorators as implemented in Python 2.4a2 is:

```
@dec2
@dec1
def func(arg1, arg2, ...):
    pass
```

> This is equivalent to:

```
def func(arg1, arg2, ...):
    pass
func = dec2(dec1(func))
```

> **without the intermediate assignment to the variable func**. (emphasis mine)

In the example I gave above, which is how the syntactic sugar is commonly explained, there is an intermediate assignment. But how does the syntactic sugar work without the intermediate assignment? A lambda function? But I also thought they could only be one line? Or is the name of the decorated function changed? It seems like that could possibly conflict with another method if the user created one coincidentally with that same name. But I don't know which is why I'm asking.

To give a specific example, I'm thinking of how a property is defined. Since when defining a property's setter method, it cannot work if the setter method is defined as that would destroy the property.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name
    # name = property(name)
    # This would work
    
    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        self._name = value.upper()
    # name = name.setter(name)
    # This would not work as name is no longer a property but the immediately preceding method
```

Comment: It's done internally by the compiler, so it doesn't have to correspond to actual python code. It just needs to have the same result.

Comment: If you want to write it yourself, you can use the "equivalent" code that it shows, I don't think it can have any negative effects.

Comment: So to be clear, syntactic sugar does NOT necessarily correspond to actual python code? The compiler takes care of it? That is my confusion as I thought by definition what separated syntactic sugar from regular code is the sugar can ultimately always be broken down to code even though that code may be verbose and difficult to read.

Comment: The equivalent works fine for the regular decorators. It does not work with properties as I tried to demonstrate. Working with properties is what triggered the question for me.

Comment: That's right. This is generally just used as a convenient way to explain what the syntax does. Except for macros systems, it's not describing the actual implementation.

Comment: Thank you! That exactly answers my question.

Comment: I think it does explain it for properties, but they're implemented as a class that defines the `.setter()` method. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property

Comment: So yes, if you were to use `property` without the decorator syntax, you would have to name the setter function differently in order not to overwrite the attribute with the function definition: `def name...; name = property(name); def namesetter...; name = name.setter(namesetter)`. But then it would make more sense to just define both getter and setter and just call `property` once, rather than sticking to the form: `def namegetter...; def namesetter...; name = property(namegetter, namesetter)`.

Comment: Syntactic sugar is basically a way to write something in a more programmer-friendlier way, but adding no expressive power to the language; if it were to be removed from the language, you could still implement the same functionality. Whether the variables will have the same names or not will not make a language weaker. Sometimes the transformation is even more drastic: JavaScript `async`/`await` are a syntactic sugar for promises, which in turn are sugar for callbacks; but transforming `async`/`await`-based code into promise- or callback-based code would require a complete restructure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def func(arg1, arg2, ...):
    pass
func = dec2(dec1(func))
```

> In the example [...] there is an intermediate assignment. But how does
> the syntactic sugar work without the intermediate assignment?

Actually, the "non syntactic sugar" version, as you call it, is not *exactly* the same as using the decorator syntax, with an `@decorator`:

As you noted, when using the `@` notation, the initial function name is never assigned a variable: the only assignment that takes place is for the resolved decorator.

So:

```
@deco
def func():
    ...
```

What is assigned to `func` in the `globals()` scope is the value returned by the call to `deco`.

While in:

```
def func():
    ...
func = deco(func)
```

First `func` is assigned to the raw function, and just as the `func=deco(func)` line is executed the former is shadowed by the decorated result.

The same apples for cascading decorators: only the final output, of the topmost decorator, is ever assigned to a variable name.

And, as well, the name used when using the `@` syntax is taken from the **source** code - the name used in the `def` statement: if one of the decorators happen to modify the function `__name__` attribute, that has no effect in the assigned name for the decorated function.

These differences are just implementation details, and derive of the way things work - I am not sure if they are on the language specs, but for those who have a certain grasp on the language, (1) they feel so natural, no one would dare implementing it differently, and (2) they actually make next to no difference - but for code that'd be tracing the program execution (a debugger, or some code using the auditing capabilities of the language (https://docs.python.org/3/library/audit_events.html )).

Despite this not being in other language specs, note however that the difference that the decorator syntax does not make the intermediate assignment is written down in PEP 318. Lacking other references, what is in the PEP is the law:

> This is equivalent to: [example without the @ syntax],
> though without the intermediate creation of a variable named func.

For sake of completeness, it is worth noting that from Python 3.10 (maybe 3.9), the syntax restriction that limited which expressions could be used as decorators after the `@` was lifted, superseding the PEP text: any valid expression which evaluates to a callable can be used now.

**what about property** ?

```
class Person:
    ...
    @property
    def name(self):
        ...
    
    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        ...
```

What takes place in this example, is that `name.setter` is a callable, called with the setter method (`def name(self, value):`) defined bellow, as usual - but what happens is that it returns a property object. (Not the same as @name - a new property, but for the purpose of understanding what takes place, it could even return the same object).

So that code is equivalent to:

```
class Person:
    ...
    def name(self):
        ...
    name = property(name)  # Creates a property with the getter only
    
    def name_setter(self, value):  # Indeed: this can't be called simply `name`: it would override the property created above
         ...

    name = name.setter(name_setter)  # Creates a new property, copying what already was set in the previous "name" and adding a setter.
    del name_setter  # optionally: removes the explicit setter from the class namespace, as it will always be called via the property.
```

In fact, while property was created before the decorator syntax (IRCC, in Python 2.2 - decorator syntax came out in Python 2.4) - it was not initially used as a decorator. The way one used to define properties in Python 2.2 times was:

```
class Person:
    ...
    def name_getter(self):
        ...
    def name_getter(self):
        ...
    name = property(name_getter, name_setter)

    del name_getter, name_setter # optional
```

It was only in Python 2.5 (or later) they made the clever ".setter" ".getter" and ".deleter" methods to properties so that it could be entirely defined using the decorator syntax.

Note that for properties with only a getter, `@property` would work from Python 2.3 on, as it would just take the single parameter supplied by the decorator syntax to be the getter. But it was not extendable to have setter and deleter afterwards.

Comment: The not-binding-the-original-function thing is mentioned in the closest thing Python has to a language spec. See [the data model docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions), particularly "except that the original function is not temporarily bound to the name `func`."

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `dis` module (`python3 -m dis Person.py`) to see how CPython implements this.

First, the (built-in) name `property` is pushed to the stack, followed by the *code* object resulting from compelling the body of the `def name` statement.

```
  5          16 LOAD_NAME                4 (property)

  6          18 LOAD_CONST               2 (<code object name at 0x108d19960, file "tmp.py", line 5>)
```

Next, the code object is turned into a function, but that function is not yet bound to a name.

```
             20 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
```

Finally, `property` is called on the function, and the resulting instance is bound to the name `name`.

```
  5          22 PRECALL                  0
             26 CALL                     0

  6          36 STORE_NAME               5 (name)
```

Next, we do the same thing for the setter. Instead of putting the name `property` on the stack, though, we put the result of evaluating `name.setter` on the stack.

```
 11          38 LOAD_NAME                5 (name)
             40 LOAD_ATTR                6 (setter)
```

Then we treat the new `name` function as before: loading a code object and making a function, but not yet binding it to any name. (Note that at this point, we neither need to the old value of the name `name`, but we don't overwrite it yet, either.)

```
 12          50 LOAD_CONST               3 (<code object name at 0x108c173c0, file "tmp.py", line 11>)
             52 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
```

Call the bound method on the new function, and bind the result back to `name`, finally replacing the old value.

```
 11          54 PRECALL                  0
             58 CALL                     0

 12          68 STORE_NAME               5 (name)
```